# Using HTML tags in JSON data processed by D3.js

Tags: html, json, d3.js, tags

I am trying to build tables based on JSON data using D3.js.
My example HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="muell"></table>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script>
    var intern_data = [{
            Proton: "A",
            Multiplett: "dd",
            Formel: "\<sup\>1\</sup\>H\<sub\>3\</sub\>"
        },
        {
            Proton: "B",
            Multiplett: "dq",
            Formel: "<sup>1</sup>C<sub>3</sub>"
        }
    ];
    var spalten = ['Proton', 'Multiplett', 'Formel'];
    tabulate("#muell", intern_data, spalten);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The Javascript is stolen from from bl.ocks.org and became a little bit modified to add the new table content into a preformatted  region.

```
var tabulate = function (table_id,data, columns) {
var table = d3.select(table_id)
var thead = table.append('thead')
var tbody = table.append('tbody')

thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d
    })

var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr')

var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function (row) {
        return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
            }
        })
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.value
    })

return table;
}
```

In principle everything works fine as long as I use plain text. Unfortunately
HTML tags become modified. For instance ">" becomes "_gt;" (& instead of _, cannot use it here, otherwise the expression becomes ">" :-) ).
I tried to use \ to keep pure HTML, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this all tags that are getting changed? Or just certain ones? Can you add an example of the output to your post.

Answer (score 1):

d3 has two functions, `text` and `html`. If you want to output html you can use the `html` function instead:

```
var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function (row) {
        return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
            }
        })
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .html(function (d) {
        return d.value
    })
```

But be careful, this is dangerous if the value doesn't come from a trusted source - since a user might be able to inject malicious HTML.

Comment: Many thanks. This immediately solved my issue. The output now is as expected. Thanks for mention the possible abuse. Actually I have to edit a lot of tables and its much easier to do this in JSON notification and parsing the JSON data.